# How can I solidify a 2d shape so that the rim isn't solidified and the center is solidified the most ? (Think creating a dome from a sphere)

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to create a teardrop shaped Jewel such as this one.

[image]

The approach I wanted to take is the create a cross section of the jewel and model it from a circle as seen here:

[image]

and then solidifying it in some way which would make the center have the most height and the keeping the rim as edges. Think of it as solidifying with a factor of 1 in the center (or the point where I choose) and that factor gradually decreases until it reaches 0 at the outer edges where they are not given any thickness.

I'm not ever sure that this would be the right approach, but it seems to be the easiest if I am able to find a modifier that created my desired effect.

Comment: So the question is "an easy approach to model the jewel in the image" right?

Comment: You can consider them 2 questions really. I'd like model the jewel in the image, yes, but I also want to know if the modification I'm asking for has a modifier and if there's a way I could create that effect, if not for this jewel then for later use in the other projects - it just seems handy.

Comment: ok now i understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do that using a modifier is to shrinkwrap the jewel to a plane, using a weighted vertex group (the plane here is displayed in wireframe mode):

[image]

Select the vertices you want to move (all except the borders).

Go to weight paint.

Validate 'vertex selection masking'

Enable X mirror

Then paint (add) the wanted vertices.

Once done, smooth the result.

[image]

After that, you can tune the influence in the modifier :

[image]

[image]

Following the comment, in order to use more easily a mirror, start from a circle, extrude inside then grid fill the inner part. That will allow you to have an edge loop or more around the jewel, so that you can connect easily the main part to the mirror center. Here is the kind of start that can be good for that :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was my first time using both the shrinkwrap modifier (though I understood how it works) and my first time learning about weight painting all together. Out of curiosity, is it possible to to use an image texture for weight painting. For example, I could take a screenshot of the 2d shape, open another program and paint some parts darker (more weight) and apply those to the shape in blender ?

Comment: @MostafaElkady, to do that, you may have a look to the displace modifier, instead of this one. Displace modifier uses a texture to displace the mesh. But this is not weight painting, though

Comment: Alright thanks! I've ran into another problem now - it's still a 2d plane. I mirrored in order to create the back as well but it remained hollow, I also tried selecting the outer vertices and selecting fill but that does not make it a solid object. I'm thinking of using the solidify modifier then using the knife tool, but is there another way ? Am I using the wrong approach for this all-together ?

Comment: @MostafaElkady, I try to give a complement to the answer for that, just a minute...

Comment: in the .blender file you attached, when I grab a vertex there is a ring around it and moving that vertex around affects the position of all vertices inside that circle. That seems like a super useful feature, how do you do that ?

Also, I'm sorry but I believe that maybe my question wasn't clear. The mirror modifier works well and I get a complete closed object, the problem is that it is hollow so I'm not able to render it with a glass material accurately as the light just passes through 2 glass planes and not a single solid object. sorry if I'm asking too much but thank you I'm learning!

Comment: @MostafaElkady... is proportional editing 'on' ? (maybe it is/was)... this is the reason. Proportional editing can be found in the 3D View buttons bar. For the other question, sorry but I nearly need to go/leave so I cannot answer you. If needed ask another question, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Check this blend file.
So what i did was i created an ico sphere then used proportional editing , created then the shape that the blue jewel in the image has and then cut it in the x axis (with knife tool) then applyed mirror modifier and tada thats it.
[image]
Keep notice that i didnt used too many faces cuz jewels arent smooth - looking
You can use the .blend file if you want :)
[image]